# How to fix my disappeared "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" menu item Android Studio 3.5 and make Android app bundle & upload key?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-play, android-app-bundle

I've tried to build "Android App Bundle" and "Upload key" with "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" menu item  Android Studio 3.5 as follows:

[image]

Then, I've required to update the Gradle plugin, so I've updated it  by selecting "Update" button As follows:
[image]

But, I've required it again.

[image]

So I've restarted the Android Studio, then the menu item "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" menu item  Android Studio 3.5? " was disappeared.

[image]
How can I fix my disappeared "Generate Single Bundle / APK" menu item, and how can I make the app bundle and upload key? Thank you for your help!

Comment: "signed", not "single" :) File a bug for Studio.

Comment: Thank you, Pierre. I've filed as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144395649#comment1.
(I've missed fixing the typo in above issue ^^;;)